# There is this mysql query i wish to get use multiple conditioned sum . As i use 2 wheres in the same line it shows an an error

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

The query is

```
SELECT ANO((SUM(AMOUNT) WHERE ANO = 101 AND TYPE = DEPOSIT) - 
           (SUM(AMOUNT) WHERE ANO = 101 AND TYPE = WITHDRAW)) AS TOTAL 
  FROM transact 
 WHERE ANO = 101;
```

The 2 Where create problem i guess.
I wish to acquire the current balance .
For eg - 101 has a deposit of 12000 and a withdraw of 2500. The output should be 9500.

[image: query on this Table]

Comment: Your query, as written, makes no sense at all.  I would suggest asking a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: ok i will edit this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want conditional aggregation:

```
select ano,
    sum(case when type = 'deposit' then amount else - amount end) as balance
from transact
where type in ('deposit', 'withdraw')
group by ano
```

If there are just two possible `type`s, then the `where` clause is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you, this works. This is a bit complex for me but will learn